Incorrect Date labels in SDID Plot Estimator (R / synthdid)
I'm doing SDID Estimator with R using Panel Data. I have historical data with the following form :
df1920trCORN
# A tibble: 192 × 7
   MONTH               CITY        PRODUCT RECEIPTS SHIPMENTS INDIVIDU  TREATMENT
   <dttm>              <chr>       <chr>      <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>         <dbl>
 1 1924-01-01 00:00:00 Chicago     CORN     7572000   4871000 Chicago_…         0
 2 1924-01-01 00:00:00 Duluth      CORN      549327         0 Duluth_C…         0
 3 1924-01-01 00:00:00 Milwaukee   CORN     1111560    981273 Milwauke…         0
 4 1924-01-01 00:00:00 Minneapolis CORN     1398940   1150010 Minneapo…         0
 5 1924-02-01 00:00:00 Chicago     CORN    13424000   4680000 Chicago_…         0
 6 1924-02-01 00:00:00 Duluth      CORN     2109283         0 Duluth_C…         0
 7 1924-02-01 00:00:00 Milwaukee   CORN     3362300   1003363 Milwauke…         0
 8 1924-02-01 00:00:00 Minneapolis CORN     3186480   1636480 Minneapo…         0
 9 1924-03-01 00:00:00 Chicago     CORN    12570000   5737000 Chicago_…         0
10 1924-03-01 00:00:00 Duluth      CORN     2637099         0 Duluth_C…         0

I'm using synthdid library to perform an econometric analysis. TREATMENT is a dummy variable (0 for non-treated observations, 1 for treated observations) My code is this:
setup = panel.matrices(as.data.frame(as_tibble(df1920trCORN)), unit=2, time=1, outcome=4,
                       treatment=7)

tau.hat = synthdid_estimate(setup$Y, setup$N0, setup$T0)
se = sqrt(vcov(tau.hat, method='placebo'))
sprintf('point estimate: %1.2f', tau.hat)
sprintf('95%% CI (%1.2f, %1.2f)', tau.hat - 1.96 * se, tau.hat + 1.96 * se)
plot(tau.hat)+
  labs(title="SDID Estimate", subtitle="Corn : 1920's", x="Date", y="Value")+
  theme_clean()

The function works perfectly but my date (period) labels are incorrect. In the plot, i have this result :

The date labels are in float format while in my data i have date with Date format. The result of the model is also misformatted for the dates
$estimate
[1] -5300965

$se
     [,1]
[1,]   NA

$controls
            estimate 1
Minneapolis      0.425
Milwaukee        0.378
Duluth           0.197

$periods
            estimate 1
-1391212800      0.465
-1446508800      0.318
-1388534400      0.131

$dimensions
          N1           N0 N0.effective           T1           T0 T0.effective 
       1.000        3.000        2.760       23.000       25.000        2.928 

Also, i don't have the standard error of the estimator.
Can you help me to solve the date problem and the standard error issue ?
Regards,
Constantin
